# MultiDomainManagementService.RetrieveAllDomainUserAlias() equivalent

Tags: c#, google-directory-api

In GData there was a method to retrieve all the aliases in a domain does Google API have an equivalent method or what would be best practice for an comparable solution?

Full path of old method - Google.GData.Apps.MultiDomainManagementService.RetrieveAllDomainUserAlias()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this link helps -
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases

The list method returns all aliases.